# How to export new data into new lines in csv using Python?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data fetched from an API to a csv file but when I get a new data the code write to the first line of the csv, and it should be on a new line. So what's the problem with the code below?

```
def start(self):
    check = []
    latest_result = None
    
    while True:
        try:
            self.date_now = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
            
            results = []
            time.sleep(1)

            response = requests.get(self.url_API)
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            formatted_timestamp = timestamp.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
            
            for i in json_data['results']:
                results.append(i)
                latest_result = i
            
            if check != results:
                check = results
                print(f'''{results[0]}, {formatted_timestamp}''')

                csv_file = "output.csv"

                # Open the CSV file in write mode
                with open(csv_file, mode="w", newline="") as file:
                    writer = csv.writer(file)

                    # Write each item as a separate row
                    
                    writer.writerows([results[0]])

                self.delete()
                self.estrategy(results)
            
        except:
            print("ERROR - 404!")
            continue
```

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about the data _only_ being written to the first line? If that's the case, I believe it is because you are opening the CSV in "write-only". If you want to "append" the data, so that each new line is not being overwritten, change the file open to `mode="a"`

Comment: That's it!!! Solved!!!

Comment: glad to help, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Sure and I will mark it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your data is *only* being written to the first line is because you are opening the file in `w` - *write only* mode, when you want to `a` - *append* the data.

The second argument to the file open function: `open(file, mode, ...)` specifies the **mode** in which the file will be opened, including:

`r` – "Read-only" is the default, and opens the file for reading.

`w` – "Write only" opens a file for writing. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file. Otherwise, as is the case here, this mode will ***overwrite*** the data that already exists in the file.

`a` – "Append" will *also* open a new file if one does not exist. But if the file *does* exist, this mode will ***append*** the data to the end of the file without overwriting it. **This is the mode you want.**

Simply change the `mode="w"` to `mode="a"` and the data will append to the end of the file instead of overwriting the existing data each time:

```
with open(csv_file, mode="a", newline="") as file:
```